# Using monomvn to impute monotone missings

Tags: r, missing-data, lasso, regularization

I am attempting to use the monomvn package to impute monotone missings.  I've followed the basic example:

```
data(cement.miss)
out <- monomvn(cement.miss)
```

However none of the outputs seem like the original input with missing imputed.  I'm sure I'm missing something.  Apologies in advance if this question is amateurish.  I'm a computer scientist tasked with doing some statistical work =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full disclosure: I haven't used `monomvn` before, but glancing at the help files, it doesn't appear that it's really meant to directly impute missing data. Rather it seems intended be a way to estimate the multivariate normal distribution of data with lots of missing values, which is an important difference.

If your goal is data imputation, perhaps you should investigate some other imputation method. I'm most familiar with imputation using random forests, but there's an enormous amount of literature out there on this topic.

Maybe one way to get started would be to try running `findFn("impute")` from the `sos` package.

Comment: thanks so much!  also, thanks for the pointer to the sos package